# trouble with showing content after it is hidden in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was doing a programming challenge from lynda.com (about jquery).
I was asked to make it so that check boxes would allow the user to hide products for a page about selling sport/health products when they are unchecked and show them back in the list when they are checked again. I could get the catigories to hide when I uncheck the check box, but they won't show again when I check it again.
Here is JQuery code first (I apologize for not great indentation):

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
      var combo = $("input[name=vitamin]").add("input[name=proteinbar]").add("input[name=mineralwater]");
      combo.on("change", function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        if (!$(this).checked) {
          filterList(name, $(this));
        }
        if ($(this).checked) {
          unfilterList(name, $(this));
        }
      });
    });

    function filterList(name, selector) {
      $(".product-item").each(function(index) {
        if (($(this).children("h2").data("type") == name) && !selector.checked) {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }

    function unfilterList(name, selector) {
      $(".product-item").each(function(index) {
        if (($(this).children("h2").data("type") == name)) {
          $(this).show();
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form >
          show:</br>
          <input type="checkbox" checked value="mineralWater" name="mineralwater" />Mineral Water <br>
          <input type="checkbox" value="proteinbar" name="proteinbar" checked /> protein bars
          <input type="checkbox" checked value="Vitamins" name="vitamin" /> vitamins <br>
      </form>
      <ul class="product-list">
        <li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-A1037">
            <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-a.jpg" alt="Vitamin A - Product Photo">
            <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin A</h2>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-BC2178">
            <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-bcomplex.jpg" alt="B Complex - Product Photo">
            <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin-B Complex</h2>
        </li>
        <li class="product-item" data-prod_id="MW-8812">
            <img class="product-image" src="images/products/mineralwater-blueberry.jpg" alt="Blueberry Mineral Water - Product Photo">
            <h2 class="product-name" data-type="mineralwater">Blueberry Mineral Water</h2>
        </li>
```

Comment: if this is a challenge for you i think you should do it yourself.

Comment: I did most of the day. I got half of it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `$(this).checked` to `this.checked` or `$(this).prop('checked')`, I think.

Comment: Or `$(this).is(":checked")`

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I don't understand, but I like it! Thank you

Comment: @hamero `$(this)` is a jQuery object which have no 'checked' property, so `$(this).checked` is undefined(false) forever. but `this.checked` will change with your click, because `this` is refer to the checkbox. and so `$(this).prop('checked')` will work as well.